# problem receiving Data on HandleHTTPRequest not working properly

Tags: port, iot, apache-nifi, httphandler, processor

I have a problem with the HandleHTTPRequest Processor, I'm using it to receive Data from Sensors via a path and a port, the problem is that even If sensors send Data and when using wireshark I see Data coming from sensors to my Integration server in the port assigned  , but the processor doesn't show anything until I restart NIFI , Data reach the processor for some minutes or sometime for 2 days and after it stop again , don't know what is the problem , because restarting Nifi every time is not a good solution for me , someone can help me on that ?

[image: NIFI FLOW]

Comment: Maybe http request from your device not finished?

Comment: didn't get your point !

Comment: It's possible that http request not finished. For example size declared 100bytes but real bytes less then 100. Could you share the  wireshark log of one request?

Comment: Another thing-have you set up handlehttpresponse processor for handlehttprequest and are you sure it triggered for all requests?

Comment: yes the process is configured , and works sometime and sometime no , this is what I find weird ,  where can I find the wireshark log ?

Comment: You have to be sure that handlehttpresponse triggered for all requests. Otherwise all the workers in  the controller service will be busy to process all requests. I don't know Wireshark - you noted it in question. Share the flow between request and response maybe we will see the unhandled relations.

Comment: I don't know what you want to know exactly !!

Comment: For each handlehttprequest you must have handlehttpresponse. Make a screenshot of your flow between those two processors and add it to the question.

Comment: Hi I have added the screenshot of the flow

Comment: Try to set failure relation for httpresponse to logattribute to see if there are some response errors. Think about replying to device in paralell with pushing to kafka to minimize delay between request-reply. Also check if you are not replying something unexceptable for your devices - because you are transmitting replacetext-failure to httpresponse : the clients could terminate connections on unexceptable data. Finally share configs for http request, response, controller, and number of concurrent devices.

Comment: to have failure working , something must at least reach one of the processors , but as you see nothing is happening

Comment: Means the whole request pool in (controller service) is blocked .

Comment: blocked by what , this is the question

Comment: Without additional info (configs and nifi logs) hard to say "what". For example if StandardHttpContextMap is full (responses for previous requests were not sent) then HandleHttpRequest will not accept any incoming requests.

Comment: The Nifi Node has 32 G RAM and 250 G for NIFI LOGS , and the Error in the log is : ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.a.n.p.standard.HandleHttpRequest HandleHttpRequest[id=587f7250-0166-1000-17bd-bd4dda2f98e1] Failed to process session due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Failed to initialize the server

Comment: Please add full stacktrace from log file to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by increasing the Request expiration which was set to 1 min [Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8g49.png)